# Automatic Volume settings?

Tags: audio

When I watch a Movie on my Desktop PC - Fedora 14 - In many times the Movie is too quiet to hear, but sometimes....it's too loud - Because there's suddenly music, or an explosion, that's really loud...

Are there any solutions/script or anything to make the sound volume constant? E.g.: the volume automatically turns down, if there is a loud explosion in the Movie, or something?

Comment: I will try out VLC's Audio normalizing with the option "10"

Comment: ladspa for pulseaudio [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/219921/46437)

Comment: Something avaliable at system level would be welcome, is it possible at least to set maximum threshold...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the built-in Audio normalizer of VLC Player did the trick. Ty!

Answer (score 5):

A *compressor* does exactly that. Some advanced media players having an option for that.

E.g. `mplayer` has the `volnorm` audio filter that does something to normalize the volume (I don't know whether it's strictly a compressor). You can use it on the command-line by the option

```
mplayer -af volnorm
```

If you want to use another movie player that doesn't have built-in support, you can do it on the audio system level. For ALSA, you could use LADSPA plugins [as described here (containing specific instructions for using a compressor)](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Ladspa_%28plugin%29).